# Orchard CMS Module Install with IISExpress Fails because of permissions

Tags: orchardcms

I keep getting the "There was an error installing the requested package. This can happen if the server does not have write access to the '~/Modules' or '~/Themes' folder of the web site. If the site is running in shared hosted environement, adding write access to these folders sometimes needs to be done manually through the Hoster control panel. Once Themes and Modules have been installed, it is recommended to remove write access to these folders." message when trying to install a module from the Gallery.

I've given the IIS_WPG full control of the Orchard.Web\Modules directory and it worked yesterday, but it doesn't today.

I'm running from Visual Studio 2010 SP1 and IIS Express.

EDIT: I've made sure the gallery path is: http://packages.orchardproject.net/FeedService.svc/

Comment: Can you try to attach a debugger and make it break on exceptions, then try again? It should give more information on the exact cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across the same issue.  We had a custom theme and I had to change the version from 1 to 1.0 in the theme.txt file. Then I was able to install a module.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by doing this:

1. Change the app pool user to NetworkService or to a custom user you
   create. (I was using IIS not IIS Express)
2. Grant read/write permissions to the user on the folders (Modules and
   Themes).
3. Make sure Dashboard > Settings > Gallery url is
   http://packages.orchardproject.net/FeedService.svc/

That fixed it for me.  Using ApplicationPoolIdentity did not work, even when I gave it the appropriate permissions (not sure why).

I hope that helps.